# Mac - copy screenshot to clipboard at 200+ percent zoom: how to control this

Tags: macos, screenshot

I just got a MacBook with the retina display and when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> I get the expected behavior: it copies the selected area as a screenshot to my clipboard. The problem is that it copies it 200+ percent zoom. Shrinking it down to the right size makes it pixelated and so I'm not getting an accurate screenshot (as I see it when it's taken).

Are there settings somewhere I can change to make it copy at the zoom level I actually work at?

ADD:
My boss has an older Mac without retina display and he doesn't have this problem. I don't know if it has anything necessarily to do with retina display though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a setting to automatically scale down the screenshot, but here are a few alternatives:

1. Use [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com/).
2. After taking the screenshot, open the **Preview** application, press ⌘N to paste the screenshot into a new document, then select **Tools > Adjust Size...** and scale to 50% with **Scale proportionally** and **Resample image** checked. This should create a smooth sharp non-pixellated image. Then press ⌘A (**Select All**) followed by ⌘C (**Copy**), and you'll have the scaled-down screenshot in your clipboard.
3. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.machoe.com/10313/auto-scale-down-retina-screenshots.html) to create a folder action which will automatically scale down screenshot image files.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Automator.
- Select the Service template
- Set: Service receives 'no input' in 'any application'
- Drag 'Run Shell Script' from the left to the right
- Add the following script:

> ```
> # Variables
> NOW=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d at%l.%M.%S %p")
> homedir=~
> eval homedir=$homedir
> SS_PATH="$homedir/Desktop"
> SS_FILE="Screen Shot $NOW"
>
> # execute screen capture command, screenshot$NOW.png is the name of file
> screencapture -i -r "$SS_PATH/$SS_FILE@2X.png"
>
> # get the 50% width of screenshot by sips
> WIDTH=$(($(sips -g pixelWidth "$SS_PATH/$SS_FILE@2X.png" | cut -s -d ':' -f 2 | cut -c 2-)/2))
>
> # scale down by sips
> sips --resampleWidth $WIDTH "$SS_PATH/$SS_FILE@2X.png" --out "$SS_PATH/$SS_FILE.png"
>
> # remove the native screenshot
> rm "$SS_PATH/$SS_FILE@2X.png"
> ```

- Save (remember the name)
- Open System Preferences and go to Keyboard
- Select Shortcuts then select Services
- Scroll down to the General section and select the name
- Add a shortcut: **Command + Shift + 5**

This will create a scaled down screen capture on your desktop

I would prefer doing this in the clipboard as we all use that more often. Anyone up for the challenge?